# why do we append '?' after data declaration in mvc model

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, model

What is use of appending '?' after data declaration in MVC in the model?

```
     <DataType(DataType.[Date])>
    Public Property p_Date_Start As Date?
```

Comment: That means that Date can be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It declares a nullable type. Have a read of the following.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: It's worth noting that this is only necessary for Value types (ie structs and base types) as all Reference types are already capable of being null.

Answer (score 1):

In c#, simple types such as int, float, double etc. (not string) cannot be null. There are however situation where a programmer would like to have an additional option to assign null to a simple variable--e.g. when value is not defined by a user. Adding ? such as:

```
int? x = 2;
double? y = null;
```

indicates that null can be assigned to a variable.

PS. It is worth reading about [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator as well. Here's the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)